# Matrix length too big?

Tags: vertical-alignment, matrices

I wanna write something quite simple, namely:

10 10 10 9 9 8 8 6 6 4 4

10 10 10 9 9 8 8 6 6 4 4

I tried the following code:

```
\begin{matrix}
10 & 10 & 10 & 9 & 9 & 8 & 8 & 6 & 6 & 4 & 4\\
10 & 10 & 10 & 9 & 9 & 8 & 8 & 6 & 6 & 4 & 4
\end{matrix}
```

However upon compilation the last "4" standing at the end of each row gets shifted to the next row standing all by itself so I get something like this:

10 10 10 9 9 8 8 6 6 4

4

10 10 10 9 9 8 8 6 6 4

4

I would like to avoid this behaviour and force the "4" in the position. Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 2):

The `amsmath` documentation (http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex-dev/amsmath/amsldoc.pdf, footnote on p.13) says 10 columns is the max,by default.  However, the counter `MaxMatrixCols` can be be increased.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{15}
\[\begin{matrix}
10 & 10 & 10 & 9 & 9 & 8 & 8 & 6 & 6 & 4 & 4\\
10 & 10 & 10 & 9 & 9 & 8 & 8 & 6 & 6 & 4 & 4
\end{matrix}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]